# java: where to store application data? (window sizes/positions, "profile" names, etc.)

Tags: java, persistence, preferences

Where should I store my user-configurable application data in Java? (e.g. the platform-independent equivalent of the Registry)

I've actually done this before, but I forget how or what terms to google :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

never mind, it's the [Preferences API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/preferences.html).

Comment: That's preference and configuration data, not necessarily the application data. You might want to rephrase the question & title if you meant pref/config data.